# Is it possible to omit field in where clause in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlc

In SQL I have following code:

```
-- name: FilterRecords :many
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE industry_id = $3 and region_code = $4 and city_code = $5
OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to exclude industry_id from where clause if provided value for it is blank string. Because when I'm making query it's counting blank strings, but I want to omit it if it's blank and select only records where they match region_code and city_code.

Comment: Please show both sample data and the expected result as tables in your question.

Comment: `(industry_id = $3 or '' = $3)`

Comment: What @Stu said will do the trick. What I usually do in similar cases is: 
COALESCE(NULLIF($3, ''), industry_id) = industry_id
just in case a NULL value sneaks in, instead of an empty string.

Comment: @D.Tabakov That worked perfectly as I wanted to do and it's so simple. Thank you!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the one made for me and worked correctly.

```
-- name: FilterApz :many
SELECT *
FROM apz
WHERE industry_id LIKE COALESCE(NULLIF($3, ''), '%%') and region_code = $4 and city_code = $5
OFFSET $1 LIMIT $2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by golangs default `text/template`.

```
variables := map[string]interface{} {
    "industry_id": ...,
    "region_id": ...,
    "city_code": ...,
    "offset": ...,
    "limit": ...,
}

qs := new(strings.Builder)

template.Must(template.New("qt").Parse(`
SELECT *
FROM records where
    {{ if .industry_id-}} industry_id= {{.industry_id}} and {{- end }}
    region_code = {{.region_code}} and city_code = {{.city_code}}
OFFSET {{.offset}} LIMIT {{.limit}}`)).
        Execute(qs, variables)

fmt.Printf("qs: %v\n", qs.String())
```

Comment: *note:* this example is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: But parameters will be parsed from somewhere with there associated type then it will be put in map[string]interface{}. It that is the case then no risk.

Comment: if my city code was "NYC; DROP TABLE records;" then I would drop your table and the next line would error.  Assuming all the inputs are properly sanitized then yes the string template will  work